# How to express internal energy in terms of the canonical function summing over energy levels?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

as far as I understand, the canonical partition function of a single particle can be expressed as follows:
$$ z = \sum_i e^{-\beta\cdot\epsilon_i} $$
Where $i$ are the micro states, $\beta$ is the inverse of the product of the Boltzman constant and the temperature, and $\epsilon_i$ is the energy at that state. Which can be expanded for a system of N particles as: $ Z=z^N$.
Where Z can be expressed
$$ Z=\sum_i e^{-\beta\cdot E_i} = \sum_j w(E_j)\cdot e^{-\beta\cdot E_j}$$
Where j represents the energy level, and $w$ is the degeneracy of that energy level. So at this point I have my first question:

1. Are $\epsilon$ from the single particle partition function and $E$, from the system's partition function different?

Then the probability of occupancy of a micro state is given by:
$$ P_i(E_i)= \frac{e^{-\beta\cdot E_i}}{Z} $$
And the probability of an energy level being occupied is:
$$ P(E_j)= \frac{w(E_j)\cdot e^{-\beta\cdot E_j}}{Z} $$

And finally, the average energy can be equated to the internal energy. Which can be calculated as follows:
$$ U=\bar{E}=\sum_i P_i(E_i)\cdot E_i $$

And here the second question:

2. What would be the equivalent of the internal energy in terms of a summation over the energy levels ($j$) instead of the micro states ($i$)?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: But partition function for N particles $Z=z^n$ is correct for only maxwell-boltzmann statistics, right ? For quantum statistics, we cannot do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe expanding the equation $Z=z^N$ explicitly will be helpful
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z&=z^N\\
&=(\sum_ie^{-\beta \epsilon_i})^N\\
&=(\sum_{i_1}e^{-\beta \epsilon_{i_1}})\cdot(\sum_{i_2}e^{-\beta \epsilon_{i_2}})\cdots(\sum_{i_N}e^{-\beta \epsilon_{i_N}})\\
&=\sum_{i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_N}e^{-\beta(\epsilon_{i_1}+\epsilon_{i_2}+\cdots+\epsilon_{i_N})}
\end{aligned}
$$
And now we can see
$$
E_i = \epsilon_{i_1}+\epsilon_{i_2}+\cdots+\epsilon_{i_N}
$$
So for the first question, $\epsilon$ is different from $E$.

For the second question, I think
$$
\begin{aligned}
U=\bar{E}&=\sum_iP_i(E_i)E_i\\
&=\sum_jP(E_j)E_j\\
&=\sum_j\frac{w(E_j)e^{-\beta E_j}}{Z}E_j
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: For $N$ particle system, should not you get $U = N \bar{E} $ ?

Comment: The $\bar{E}$ in your equation is the energy of a single particle, but in our equations it means the energy of the total $N$ particles.